# When I add a new section (by stepper), the content of the cells in a section mixes with content of another section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've a tableView with dynamic cells. Each section has 5 rows. In the first 4 rows for each row there is a text field. Instead in the fifth row there is an imageview (when I click on this row, I can choose a photo from my photo library, and this last will be put in imageView). The number of sections is decided at run-time using a stepper. The section 0 is fixed and contains a stepper. When I click on + button (on stepper) a section will be add. So everything is right but if I wrote before in the rows that contain the textfield, and then add one or more sections, the contents of these textfield are mixed with each other (and also between sections).

```
//In file.h I've declared @property (nonatomic) int numberOfComponents;

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1 + self.numberOfComponents;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 4;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellStepper";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UILabel *stepperLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        stepperLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.numberOfComponents];
        UIStepper *stepper = (UIStepper *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        stepper.minimumValue = 0;
        stepper.maximumValue = 20;
        stepper.stepValue = 1;
        stepper.autorepeat = YES;
        stepper.continuous = YES;
        return cell;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 4) {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellProfileSnap";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    }

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellDetail";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *cellLabelComponent = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    cellLabelComponent.placeholder = @"detail";
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)stepperClik:(UIStepper *)stepper{
    if (stepper.value == 0 && self.numberOfComponents == 0) {
        if (stepper.value > self.numberOfComponents) {
            self.numberOfComponents += 1;

        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }


    if (stepper.value > self.numberOfComponents) {
        self.numberOfComponents += 1;

    }
    else{
        self.numberOfComponents -= 1;

    }


    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

[image]

[image]

Solved by Greg, but now there's another problem: I have a save button, which should save many arrays into a dictionary (containing the details of each section 5) as the number of sections.
Here the code of save button:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender{

    NSMutableArray *arrComponents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < self.numberOfComponents; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray *component = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int j = 0; j < [self.arrDetails count]; j++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i+1];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        if (j == 4){
            UIImageView *imageComponent = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
            NSLog(@"%@",imageComponent.image);
            if (imageComponent.image == Nil) {
                [component addObject: nil];
            }
            [component addObject: imageComponent.image];
        }
        else{
            UITextField *detailComponent = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
            NSLog(@"%@",detailComponent.text);
            if ([detailComponent.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
                [component addObject:@""];
            }
            if (detailComponent.text != nil && i != 0)
                [component addObject: detailComponent.text];
        }

    }
    [arrComponents addObject: component];
    NSLog(@"%@",arrComponents);
}
```

Where it is shown in the code / / ERROR HERE, at the fourth iteration of 5 iterations (number of rows in a section) of the latest iteration (last section read), the application crashes giving this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your detailComponent is equal nil and you cannot save nil to the array. Before you call

```
[component addObject: detailComponent.text]; //ERROR HERE
```

do check:

```
if (detailComponent != nil && i != 0)
    [component addObject: detailComponent.text];
```

It could happen because in your section 0 you haven't got any textfield.

//EDITED

The issue is happened here:

```
if (imageComponent.image == Nil) {
    [component addObject: nil];
}
[component addObject: imageComponent.image];
```

Replace it with:

```
if (imageComponent.image == nil) {
    [component addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
else {
    [component addObject: imageComponent.image];
}
```

You cannot add nil to array if you want to add nil you should add object NSNull.
And you are missing else statement. Your code try to add nil to the array twice (if the image is nil) first time in your if statement ([component addObject: nil];) and second time just after your if statement: [component addObject: imageComponent.image];

// EDITED

Make the changes as suggested in comments in code below. I use the same dictionary, you should change the name because it suggest that it keeps just textfields values, but now it will store the images as well:

```
    if (indexPath.row == 4) {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellProfileSnap";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //I believe this is where you keep your imageView
        // get your image 
        UIImageView *imageComponent = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sec:%d,row:%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
        if (self.textValueDictionary[key])
            imageComponent.image = self.textValueDictionary[key];
        else
            imageComponent.image = nil; //Your default value (probably you want to set up your plus image)
        return cell;
    }
```

The next step you need to make is where the user presses the plus image - you have to save the image in the dictionary. Put this code to your method where you get the image from user. This is a pseudo code so you have to adjust it a little bit:

```
// Get reference to the cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = //have a look on textFieldDidEndEditing  method. You have to work out how to get the cell (I cannot do that because I haven't got access to your code);
    // Get index path
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Get section as a string
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sec:%d,row:%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    UIImage *img = //get your image here;
    //make sure it's not nil before you save it to dictionary
    //save it to dictionary
    [self.textValueDictionary setValue:img forKey:key];
```

The last bit is saveButton: method there was mistake in my advices from yesterday. You're trying to get text and image directly from cells, and it works fine if the cells are visible. If you cannot see the cell system put it to reusable pool and you get nils.
To fix it you have to get the data from the dictionary:
Don't use:

```
  UIImageView *imageComponent = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
```

instead do:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sec:%d,row:%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    UIImage *img = self.textValueDictionary[key];
    // make sure is not nil before you save it. If it's nil add [NSNull nil] to your array as I explained before.
```

When you read text don't do it like that:

```
UITextField *detailComponent = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
```

get text from the dictionary:

```
     NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sec:%d,row:%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
        NSString *str = self.textValueDictionary[key];
```

If it complain about data type use cast (UIImage*).
Remember to change your first loop to: for (int i = 1; i < self.numberOfComponents; i++) and when you get NSIndexPath change it to inSection:i instead inSection:i+1.
I haven't run this in Xcode so maybe there are some mistakes but you should be able to find and fix it.
Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I have tried to insert 2 sections with this details: - John - Black - Man - Business - Image (for imageView) --------- - James - Morrison - Man - Commerce - Image (for imageView) --------- Using NSLog(@"%@",imageComponent.image); and NSLog(@"%@",detailComponent.text); and NSLog(@"%@",arrComponents); results of debug at the end of app (crash) is: [1217:a0b] John [1217:a0b] Black [1217:a0b] Man [1217:a0b] Business [1217:a0b] <UIImage: 0x10a5ba070> [1217:a0b]"<UIImage: 0x10a5ba070>" [1217:a0b]James [1217:a0b]Morrison [1217:a0b]Man [1217:a0b](null) [1217:a0b](null) –  object cannot be nil

Comment: Have you got image in section 2 (James morrison)?

Comment: Ok, but why it don't take the last two fields (last textfiled and image) of the last inserted section?

Comment: It doesn't work! It give to me the same result (but adding another text null)

Comment: If you still get nil from your image it because the cell reusable and you need to do the same trick as with UITextFields. Add some dictionary and if user add the image save it in dictionary and after that display it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Nothing yet! How can I do this last step (last comment you left) .can you make it editing the old post? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! You're a really great! Thank you very much!

Comment: help me please, now there is a new problem: if I didn't touch a row with my finger, it's not recorded in textValueDictionary

Comment: This is a different problem. Please create new question, explain exactly what's wrong (it's not enough when you just say I didn't touch a row with my finger, it's not recorded in textValueDictionary , and post some code which you think cause this issue.

Comment: here the new post, please can you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634040/save-the-contents-of-dynamic-cells-at-run-time-with-textfielddidendediting

Comment: Greg have you seen the post??

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you don't save the cellLabelComponent.text property and when you reloadData tableView reuses cell (which cause this problem).
You should save data you entered to your cellLabelComponent (for example in array, you can use UITextFieldDelegate) and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method you should assign saved values to desired field.

//EXTENDED

Conform to `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol in your .h file or class extension.
Add

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *textValueDictionary;`

to your class extension and allocate it and init in viewDidLoad or init method:

```
self.textValueDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Add this to cellForRowArIndexPath:

```
    cellLabelComponent.placeholder = @"detail";
    // Make your class to be delegate for UITextField
    cellLabelComponent.delegate = self;
    // I use NSString (section) as a key in my dictionary. You can use NSNumber if you like
    if (self.textValueDictionary[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section]])
        cellLabelComponent.text = self.textValueDictionary[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section]];
    else
        cellLabelComponent.text = @""; //Your default value
```

Add your UITextFieldDelegate methods:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Get reference to the cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[[textField superview] superview] superview];
    // Get index path
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Get section as a string
    NSString *section = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section];
    [self.textValueDictionary setValue:textField.text forKey:section];
}
```

You can use more delegate if you need.
It should be enough to make it works. It will work just when you have one UITextField in your table section if you have more you should use unique key in your dictionary (NSindexPath will work if you have more that one textfield in section but not more that one in row, just remember to convert it to NSNumber).
Let me know is it work.

//EXTENDED

If you have more that one UITextField per section you have to change the dictionary key. This solution above will work just if you have up to one row per section.

This solution (below) will work if you have many textfields per section but not more that one text field per cell (it will work for one textfield per section as well):
Change line in cellForRowAtIndexPath from:

```
if (self.textValueDictionary[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section]])
    cellLabelComponent.text = self.textValueDictionary[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section]];
```

to:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sec:%d,row:%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
if (self.textValueDictionary[key])
    cellLabelComponent.text = self.textValueDictionary[key];
```

And change lines in textFieldDidEndEditing: method from:

```
NSString *section = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section];
[self.textValueDictionary setValue:textField.text forKey:section];
```

to:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sec:%d,row:%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
[self.textValueDictionary setValue:textField.text forKey:key];
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: it doesn't work properly, in the sense that each section is repeated always the last row

Comment: 5 rows (4 that contain textfield, 1 that contain an imageView)

Comment: Have you got just one textField in one row (no more than 1 per row)?

Comment: Yes, 1 textField for each row

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! You are great! But now read the last issue I had! Look, I've added to the end of the initial application!

Comment: help me please, now there is a new problem: if I didn't touch a row with my finger, it's not recorded in textValueDictionary

Comment: here the new post, please can you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634040/save-the-contents-of-dynamic-cells-at-run-time-with-textfielddidendediting

Comment: Greg have you seen the post??

Comment: please Can you See my new post?